# Unable to invoke HTTP Cloud Function with user auth token

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I deployed a Callable Cloud Function and would like to test it with some POST requests. Here is the Python code of the deployed function:

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_call()
def my_function(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> Any:
    try:
        recId = req.data["recId"]
        return {"passedRecId": recId}
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        raise https_fn.HttpsError(
            code=https_fn.FunctionsErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
            message=("The function was called with incorrect arguments"),
        )
```

I assigned my user with required roles, as mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_developer_testing), such as:

- Cloud Functions Developer
- Cloud Functions Invoker (`cloudfunctions.functions.invoke`)

When I try to execute the curl command as suggested in the testing tab,

```
curl -m 130 -X POST https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction \
-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"data": {"recId": "6lKMe3XgbBQ6hvba5N1j"}}'
```

I get the following error:

> WARNING:root:Callable request verification failed: $[('Auth token was rejected.', {'app': 'MISSING', 'auth': 'INVALID', 'logging.googleapis.com/labels': {'firebase-log-type': 'callable-request-verification'}})]"

It also fails when I run it in cloud shell. I browsed the docs multiple times and can't wrap my head around why my authentication is invalid. Is there another permission missing that I am not aware of? Any guidance will be appreaciated.

Comment: Are you using an Identity Token or Access Token? Show how you created the token. Show how you are using the token. I recommend testing with the CLI tool `curl` so that you can post the results in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated my question with the curl command, which is the one suggested in the docs for testing purposes.

Comment: What is the minimal code of the function that you deployed? It's not clear what you mean by "Python Callable Cloud Function". What do you expect it to do with this token?

Comment: @DougStevenson updated the question with the deployed Cloud Function code. I would expect it to return `{"result":{"passedRecId":"6lKMe3XgbBQ6hvba5N1j"}}` in the concrete example I'm providing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I followed the following [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) to create a callable function with Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callable functions don't use GCP service accounts to authenticate.  They use Firebase Authentication user accounts.  The expected use case for callable functions is that they're invoked from a web or mobile app frontend that uses Firebase Auth for user authentication, as you can see from the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#call_the_function).  The Firebase-provided libraries automatically use the ID token for the currently signed in user to invoke the function.

If you're writing a function that doesn't need to be invoked by a frontend that uses Firebase, then don't use callable type functions.  Also, if aren't using the Firebase CLI to deploy, don't use the Firebase libraries.  You should probably just use the normal GCP functions without Firebase as described in the [GCP tutorial for python functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-gcloud#%0Afunctions-prepare-environment-python).

Comment: I am deploying the function with Firebase CLI (v13.0.2). It is indeed supposed to be  invoked from a mobile app. However, as a developer of the function, I must have a way to be able to test is somehow **after** the deployment, right? The following command doesn't work either, with 401 error:
`gcloud functions call my_function --region=us-central1 --data '{  "data": {"recId": "6lKMe3XgbBQ6hvba5N1j"} }' --gen2`

Comment: Sure, follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) to understand the protocol it uses.  But you can't make up user accounts to provide.  Those must be real Firebase Auth user account ID tokens from your project, or nothing at all.

Comment: I reached out to mobile app developer consuming this function and he still gets `[firebase_functions/unauthenticated] UNAUTHENTICATED`.  Here is how he calls it: `final token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken(); final callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('myFunction');` and finally `final result = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{'recId': 'xxx', 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});`. Only granting `allUsers` invoke permission helps, but it is a major security concern for us. Could you confirm if setting `allUsers` permission is the only solution here?

Comment: allUsers is required for functions that need to be invoked from outside GCP by web and mobile applicactions.

Comment: @DougStevenson, do you have a basic working example with a Python firebase function being called from a firebase app (with or without auth) that works? I've been following the tutorials exactly and keep getting errors. I'm starting to think the Python implementation just doesn't work, since most examples are with JS firebase functions. I've successfully run Google Cloud functions (different), but no luck with firebase functions, nor have I seen anyone with it working.